# Task list permissions

Tags: permissions, task-list

I am new to the SharePoint and I have some problem hope you help me in my task list

1. I want to grant edit task permission only to `Assigned to` & `Created by`
2. I have many departments in my company and I want to  have those departments running their separate task list or project. And there is certain manager can read the tasks of other departments

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: please any one who have a solution share with me

Comment: msds-badi@outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

You can't set permission to anything smaller than SPListItem which means you can't grant permissions to columns using OOTB SharePoint.

However you can use Javascript tools like Dynamic Forms to specify which columns can be edit by whome.

For your second point you could simply create task lists for each department, specify unique permissions for those lists and have a group of supervisor which can read all tasks.

Comment: thanks Andreas . could you give me step by step guide for the first point

Comment: Hey, please have a look at this [link](spjsblog.com/2013/08/12/dynamic-forms-for-sharepoint-v3) to learn about Dynamic Forms.